# ESRI.style file not loading on citrix

Tags: arcmap, citrix, style

We have a distributed ArcMap application on a citrix farm.

We've come across a strange problem where the ESRI.style doesn't load.

If you create a session, you can then go through the style manager and load the ESRI.style  file, which is there, and it's fine.  However, if you shut down, the next time you start, the same problem exists.

There's no real logic to it.   Has anyone come across this before?

I have edited this for a bit of clarity, and now I am thinking with my mouth, but I am starting to think if the user is setting the style back in the citrix session, that is why it is not being saved, so it actually needs to be done on the instances on the Citrix farm, if that makes any sense?

Comment: OK, I have fixed this.  Running C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Utilities\AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe showed the styles path to be on a non-extant drive.  Thanks.

Comment: OK< No worries @Mapperz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have fixed this. Running C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Utilities\AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe showed the styles path to be on a non-extant drive.

This does also mean you have to reset all of your symbology too, as it's been out of synch.

Also remember to do any changes to the MXD on the Citrix server farm as if you do it through teh client, it only saves changes for the session....

Cheers